# Position sub-menu item relative to main menu item, but in an outside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the sub-menu behavior of a site. The original sub-menu appears as a drop-down, and instead I'd like it to appear in a separate full horizontal div.

So far I've done this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $(".header").append("<div class='subber'><div class='sub-menu'></div></div>");

$(".main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children").mouseover( function() {
    var a = $(this).find(".sub-menu").html();
    $(".subber .sub-menu").html(a);

 }); 
});
```

... with some css, and it works well. the original sub-menu HTML is copied to the *subber* sub-menu.

I'd like each *subber* sub-menu to be positioned relatively to the original menu item, even though they occur in separate areas of the HTML. Can I somehow bind the two?

**My HTML code:**

```
<div class="header">
    <div id="navigation">
        <div class="site-navigation">
            <nav class="main-navigation">
                <ul class="menu-main-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item">
                        <a href="#">some text</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
                        <a href="#">some text</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="menu=item">
                                <a href="#">sub item text</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item">
                        <a href="#">some text</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subber">
        <div class="sub-menu"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add all relevant code here as a [mcve] and remove the external link. There is no way for us to know where that link leads, I for one will not click external links here.

Comment: thanks, i've added the html code :) sorry for noobness

Comment: This can be achieved easily using CSS, no need for javascript - but you'd need to change the HTML structure. Would that be ok?

Comment: can't change the html... would have done so :) this is why i'm trying with jquery... thx!

Comment: Did you manage to try out my solution below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no actual parent-child relationship in the HTML structure, there's no CSS-way of positioning your new sub-menu relative to a top-level menu item.

Instead, **you'll have to manually position the new sub-menu with JS, using the coordinates of the original menu item**.

Keep in mind this basic positioning won't create a "stickyness" between the two, so if your main menu moves (e.g. a sliding menu bar with up/down toggle states), you'll have to trigger an update to the sub-menu positioning using a listener and function.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/WWRWgG)

```js
$("#menuItem1").mouseover( function() {
  
  /* get original menu */
  var origMenu = $(this);
  
  /* grab content out of original sub-menu */
  var myContent = origMenu.find(".sub-menu").html();
  
  /* copy content over to new sub-menu outside of navigation */
  $(".subber .sub-menu").html(myContent);
  
  /* get the coordinates of the original menu item */
  var subberLeftOffset = origMenu.offset().left;
  var subberTopOffset = origMenu.offset().top + origMenu.innerHeight(true);
   
  /* re-position the new sub-menu so it appears below the original menu */
  $(".subber").offset({top: subberTopOffset, left: subberLeftOffset});;
 });
```

```css
#origNavigation .sub-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}


#menuItem1 {
  margin-top: 8em;
  margin-left: 8em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="origNavigation">
  <div id="menuItem1">
    Hello
  <div class="sub-menu">Sub-menu</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="subber">
  <div class="sub-menu"></div>
</div>
```